# MySQLi ->insert_id regresa valor "0"

Tags: php, html5, ajax, mysqli

Tengo un panel de administración en el cual puedes agregar aún más administradores, pero cuando intento agregarlos me regresa un error.
He revisado múltiples veces los datos enviados con `die(json_encode($_POST));` y si llegan todos los datos del formulario, pero cada que intento `die(json_encode($id_registro));` (más abajo se verá que es esta variable) me regresa "0" y por ende me arroja un error.
Si se necesita más información la puedo subir sin problemas.

```
include_once "funciones/funciones.php"; // esta es la conexión con la base de datos
$usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
$nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$id_registro = $_POST['id_registro']; // variables globales
if ($_POST['registro'] == 'nuevo') { // este es el valor de un campo oculto que me indica el tipo de modificación a la base de datos
  $opciones = array(
    'cost' => 12
  );
  $password_hashed = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $opciones);
  try {
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO admins (nombre, usuario, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?) "); //estoy seguro de que los nombres de la tabla y las columnas son correctos
    $stmt->bind_param("sss", $nombre, $usuario, $password_hashed);
    $stmt->execute();
    $id_registro = $stmt->insert_id;
    if ($id_registro > 0) {
      $respuesta = array( // esta es mi respuesta personalizada para AJAX
        'respuesta' => 'exito',
        'id_admin' => $id_registro
      );
    }else{
      $respuesta = array( //siempre me regresa esta respuesta
        'respuesta' => 'error'
      );
    }
    $stmt->close();
    $conn->close();
  } catch (\Exception $e) {
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
  }
die(json_encode($respuesta));// aqui se regresan valores a ajax
} // FIN-NUEVO
```

Esté es el AJAX que procesa la respuesta personalizada.

```
  $('#guardar-registro').on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var datos = $(this).serializeArray();
    $.ajax({
      type: $(this).attr('method'), // post, en este caso
      data: datos,
      url: $(this).attr('action'),
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        var resultado = data;
        if (resultado.respuesta == 'exito') {
          swal(
            'Correcto',
            'Se guardó correctamente',
            'success'
          )
        }else{
          swal(
            'Incorrecto',
            'Hubo un error al crear el administrador',
            'error'
          )
        }
      }
    })
  });
```

Y este es el HTML de mi formulario.

```
        <form role="form" name="guardar-registro" id="guardar-registro" method="post" action="modelo-admin.php">
          <div class="box-body">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="usuario">Usuario: </label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usuario" name="usuario" placeholder="Usuario">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="nombre">Nombre: </label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombre" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="password">Contrase&ntilde;a: </label>
              <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password para iniciar sesión">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="password">Repetir contrase&ntilde;a: </label>
              <input type="password" class="form-control" id="repetir_password" name="repetir_password" placeholder="Repetir password">
              <span id="resultado_password" class="help-block"></span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- /.box-body -->

          <div class="box-footer">
            <input type="hidden" name="registro" value="nuevo">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="crear_registro_admin">A&ntilde;adir</button>
          </div>
        </form>
```

Comment: [El Manual de PHP dice que](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.insert-id.php): ***Si la tabla modificada no tiene una columna con el atributo AUTO_INCREMENT, está función devolverá cero.*** ¿Tu tabla cumple ese requisito? Convendría también que controles lo que ocurre con la ejecución (`execute`)  mostrando eventuales mensajes de error en caso de ocurrir **otro tipo de error** como registros duplicados, nombres de tabla/columna mal escritos, etc. Generalmente los programadores de PHP son *ingenuos*  en ese tipo de control de errores. Incluso que la conexión no sea nula debería controlarse.

Comment: Además, `insert_id` es un método de la conexión, no de la sentencia, por tanto, debería ser:    `$id_registro = $conn->insert_id;` @JoseLuisEsparza puede que tenga razón en su sugerencia, la cual acaba de borrar.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUCIONADO**
Mi error se encontraba en la manera en la que volvía a enlazar mi base de datos.

```
<?php
$conn = new mysqli('localhost', '**********', '*********', '***********');

if($conn->connect_error){
  echo $error -> $conn->connect_error;
}
?> // esta es la conexión original
```

Y esta la manera en la que intenté volver a usar esa conexión

```
<?php
include_once '../funciones/conexion_bd.php';
?>
```

Así quedó una vez corregido.

```
<?php
include_once '../../funciones/conexion_bd.php';
?>
```